# Refactoring a select case statement

Tags: vb.net

I have a procedure that gets a value from a backend table when required.  I have striven to ensure that the table will only be referenced when and if the parameters that are required by the stored procedure to retrieve that value will indeed produce a value, and that has led me to the following select case statement.

I have looked at this several times with a few to trying to refactor it to make it more efficient (or at least less cumbersome) but have failed to come up with anything.  So I thought that I would ask if anyone can spot a more efficient way of doing this, and more importantly point out why it is more efficient.

To make it easier to understand this is to determine the conversion factor required to establish what the live weight of fish landed at port might have been determined by the way it was landed.  So for example if you simply land fillets of fish then a fair amount of the whole fish will have gone to waste but that waste needs to be accounted for.  PC is the Presentation Code (ie "FIL" is filleted).  Not all species (represented by SC) have conversion factors for all presentation codes, hence the need to narrow it down so that the stored procedure (GetConversionFactor) is only called when there is a likelihood that it can provide a valid conversion factor.

Many thanks for any suggestions that you might have.

```
Private Sub GetConversionFactor()
    'not all presentation codes have a conversion factor
    ' and not all codes need to be checked
    Select Case PC
        Case "WHL"
            ConversionFactor = CDec(0.0)
        Case "GUT"
            ConversionFactor = CDec(te.GetConversionFactor(SC, PC).FirstOrDefault)
        Case "GUH"
            Select Case SC
                Case "ANF", "BLL", "COD", "DAB", "HAD", "HKE", "HER", "LIN", "PLE", "POL", "POK", "WHG", "BLI", "GFB", "RNG"
                    ConversionFactor = CDec(te.GetConversionFactor(SC, PC).FirstOrDefault)
                Case Else
                    ConversionFactor = CDec(0.0)
            End Select
        Case "FIL"
            Select Case SC
                Case "BSS", "COD", "COE", "SOL", "FLE", "HAL", "HAD", "HKE", "LEM", "LIN", "LEZ", "MUL", "PLE", "POL", "MUR", "POK", "DGS", "TUR", "WHG", "WIT", "BLI", "GFB", "RNG", "SBR"
                    ConversionFactor = CDec(te.GetConversionFactor(SC, PC).FirstOrDefault)
                Case Else
                    ConversionFactor = CDec(0.0)
            End Select

        Case "TAL"
            Select Case SC
                Case "ANF", "NEP"
                    ConversionFactor = CDec(te.GetConversionFactor(SC, PC).FirstOrDefault)
                Case Else
                    ConversionFactor = CDec(0.0)
            End Select

        Case "HEA"
            Select Case SC
                Case "COD", "BSF"
                    ConversionFactor = CDec(te.GetConversionFactor(SC, PC).FirstOrDefault)
                Case Else
                    ConversionFactor = CDec(0.0)
            End Select

        Case "GUS"
            Select Case SC
                Case "FLE", "DGS"
                    ConversionFactor = CDec(te.GetConversionFactor(SC, PC).FirstOrDefault)
                Case Else
                    ConversionFactor = CDec(0.0)
            End Select

        Case "SGT"
            Select Case SC
                Case "LIN"
                    ConversionFactor = CDec(te.GetConversionFactor(SC, PC).FirstOrDefault)
                Case Else
                    ConversionFactor = CDec(0.0)
            End Select
        Case "WNG"
            Select Case SC
                Case "RJB", "RJO", "JAD", "RJA", "RJH", "RJM", "RJR", "RJC", "RJE", "RJN", "RJI", "RJU", "RJF", "TTR", "TTO", "JDP"
                    ConversionFactor = CDec(te.GetConversionFactor(SC, PC).FirstOrDefault)
                Case Else
                    ConversionFactor = CDec(0.0)
            End Select
        Case "GHT"
            Select Case SC
                Case "RNG"
                    ConversionFactor = CDec(te.GetConversionFactor(SC, PC).FirstOrDefault)
                Case Else
                    ConversionFactor = CDec(0.0)
            End Select
        Case Else
            ConversionFactor = CDec(0.0)
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: This almost surely ought to be a dbase table.  Glue PC and SC together so you have a simple lookup.  This permits altering the conversion factors and adding/removing special rules without having to alter the code.

Comment: Hans,  there is an underlying lookup table (hence the spoc call) but there are something of the order of three thousand possible combinations of SC and PC of which only 113 would return a result. I guess my question would have been better phrased as 'is it better to call a sproc knowing that in the vast majority of cases you will get nothing back, or try and ensure that you only call it when you know there is a value to be returned?'

Comment: If it's not called often, then going to the database everytime is ok. If it's called a lot, then store the results each time so that you only need to go to the database once.

Comment: That could be rather like asking how long is a piece of string, I suspect that some users could potentially call the spoc a couple of hundred times in a session, others may not call it at all.  I could conceivably create a dictionary using the combination of SC and PC as the key and reference that instead, but I'm not sure if that would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could Pre-eval PC:

```
 IF "|WHL|GUT|FIL|etc|".Contains("|" & PC) & "|" THEN
```